# PHP ajax chat without database at backend

Tags: php, ajax

Does anyone know where messages accesses without using database on php-ajax chat?
example can be found on
www.phpfreechat.net/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In files:

> By default, you don't need a Mysql
>   database. The chat uses files to store
>   messages and nicknames.

Source: http://www.phpfreechat.net/required-config